# Paginas .aspx na pasta View em projeto ASP.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Boa tarde pessoal,

sou iniciante na arquitetura MVC e estou com uma dúvida em um projeto ASPNET.MVC. Gostaria de saber se é possível na pasta "View" do projeto, colocar uma pagina "aspx" junto com os arquivos "cshtml".

Se coloco o arquivo na raiz da aplicação web, sobe tranquilamente mas ao colocar na pasta View ele gera o erro 404.

Procurei algumas soluções na web mas não encontrei muita coisa.

Desde já agradeço,

Obrigado!

Comment: Minha primeira pergunta é... por quê?

Comment: Minha segunda pergunta, qual a versão?

Comment: Olá, o motivo seria devido a migração destas paginas aspx de um sistema legado em webforms para serem organizadas na mesma pasta onde estarão as novas views do sistema

Comment: A versão seria o MVC 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso de uma migração eu recomendo que você crie uma pasta chamada "Legado" ou como "Paginas" mesmo (caso não queira deixar essa intenção explícita" e adicione o Ignore dessa rota no seu `RouteConfig` que está localizado no diretório `App_Start`. Assim o MVC vai ignorar essa rota em seu gerenciamento.

Veja o Exemplo Abaixo

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");            

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{diretorio}", new { diretorio = "Paginas" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

Comment: Blz Leandro, obrigado pela dica, para concluir o entendimento, então paginas aspx dentro da pasta padrão View, mesmo em novas implementações podem coexistir com paginas cshtml? Obrigado ;)

Comment: Você até pode ter um aspx dentro do diretório default `Views`, desde que ela derive de `ViewPage`, `ViewPage<TModel>`, `ViewUserControl`, ou `ViewUserControl<TModel>`. Inclusive, bem no início as views eram arquivos aspx e não cshtml

Comment: Excelente!, muito obrigado por compartilhar o conhecimento .Grande abraço!